# Switching containerView content from within viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have three viewControllers **Main**, **A**, **B**. **Main ViewController** holds **ContainerView** and other content as well does all transactions in containerView. **ViewControllerA** has **ButtonA** when pressing it content of container has to change to **ViewControllerB**
how can I do that? I cannot find any similar examples.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While click on ButtonA. Post a notification to mainView. There remove viewController A from Container and add View Controller B .

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create create delegate for that. 
First create a protocol

```
protocol ViewControllerADelagate {
    func didPressOnButtonA()
}
```

In ViewControllerA add following delegate variable

```
class ViewControllerA {
    ....

    var delegate : ViewControllerADelagate?
    ....
}
```

In ViewControllerA add following on button press

```
@IBAction buttonAPressed(sender : UIButton) {
    self.delegate?.didPressOnButtonA()
}
```

In MainViewController assign the delegate of ViewControllerA to self
like

```
vcA.delegate = self
```

Implement the delegate method in MainViewController like

```
func didPressOnButtonA {
        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil)
        let vcB : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerIdentifier) as! ViewControllerB
        self.addChildViewController(vcB)
        self.containerView.addSubview(vcB.view)
        vcB.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        vcB.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.containerView.frame.size.width, height: self.containerView.frame.size.height)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a storybaord with sample. you can download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nv674phsuxabi1n/SO.zip?dl=0).

You need to change the embed view to a navigation controller and then you can use segue to show second view on button press. also hide/show navigation bar depends on requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fond of using these but you can get the child view controller from parent controller by accessing an array `childViewControllers`. On view did load you would need to go through all of these and find the one that can be typecast into your view controller type like

`childViewControllers.flatMap { $0 as? AViewController }.first`.

Now that you found the correct view controller I suggest you to either assign yourself as a delegate

`childViewControllers.flatMap { $0 as? AViewController }.first.delegate = self`

or simply add a button target

`childViewControllers.flatMap { $0 as? AViewController }.first.button.addTarget...`

Now this can easily be done if you simply embed the 2 view controllers at the same time (have 2 content views) and hide one or the other depending on which you show. At least this way you can assign connection straight away. When this is not the case then you will need to iterate again when setting a new controller or assign connections where you initialize a new view controller.

In this case it then seems better to turn the system around: When child view controller is loaded rather call

```
self.delegate = parentViewController as? AViewControllerDelegate
```

Although this will work it seems wrong that a child view controller will control who its listener is so I advise you to avoid such coding.

I in general use a custom implementation for container view which you could do the same or maybe at least subclass the native one and target the methods so that your code will look something like:

```
private onBPressed() {
    containerView.setViewController(viewController: BViewController(delegate: self), animation: .fade)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you pressing `Button A` from View A:

```
@IBAction func BtnAPress(_ sender: Any)
{
   //Moving Storyboard
   let Storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   let MainVC : UIViewController = Storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerB")
   self.present(MainVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Refer this Video @03:55 minute: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2s2c8PrMZE